# Error when clicking a button using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to click on a button using the selenium, but I'm getting an error.

This is the error:

[image]

this is the fragment of the accessed html page:

[image]

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
wd.get("xxxxxx")


button = wd.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"VfPpkd-LgbsSe.VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf.ksBjEc.lKxP2d.LQeN7.x0t5t") 
button.click()
```

The objective is: When I click on the button using the selenium a popup appears on the screen

Answer (score 0):

This is (mostly) caused by element not being loaded and you're trying to perform click on it before...

Try with this:

```
WebDriverWait(wd, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'VfPpkd-LgbsSe.VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf.ksBjEc.lKxP2d.LQeN7.x0t5t'))).click()
```

Don't forget to import `WebDriverWait`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

This way you can avoid assigning value of that `button` to variable `button` and `button.click`

Comment: I receved the erro without mensage... Just:

TimeoutException: Message:

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this button just looks like a button in the html but is not a button (or even an element) on the UI.
Try to click any of the elements inside this button. There are 3 divs and one span. I suggest the span will be able to receive the click. So, try the following:

```
button = wd.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[@jsname="V67aGc"]') 
button.click()
```

Comment: I tried with all elements inside the botton and, no one is iterable...

Comment: Initially, I didn't noticed the line about the pop-up message. Is it displayed on the screen when you try to click the button? If yes, you will not be able to click the button until you close the pop-up.